# How to set date in the angular js fullcalendar in the ajax response

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I am using angular js fullcalendar control.I am calling a server method that method is returning date that date i want to set in the fullcalendar in the response of the server method.

I am doing the server call using ajax.

Here is the code which i am referring :

```
myModule.controller('calendarController', ['$scope', '$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {
  var date = new Date();
  var d = date.getDate();
  var m = date.getMonth();
  var y = date.getFullYear();
  // '1/25/2015 12:00:00 AM' AND dDueDate <= '3/8/2015 12:00:00 AM' 
  var GetEventData = {
    startDate: "1/25/2008 12:00:00 AM",
    endDate: "3/8/2016 12:00:00 AM",
    tabstate: "Org"
  };
  var url = window.opener.oT.TracerURL + "/DakotaScheduler.aspx/GetEventData";
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(GetEventData),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
  }).done(function (response) {
    var eventdate = response.d.EventDataTable[0].EventDate;
    $scope.events = [{
        title: 'test',
        start: new Date(y, m, d, 3, 0),
        end: new Date(y, m, d, 4, 0)
    }];

    $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];

  }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(errorThrown);
  });
  $scope.events = [{
        title: 'test',
        start: new Date(y, m, d, 3, 0),
        end: new Date(y, m, d, 4, 0)
    }];
    $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];
}]);
```

What is happening in this example

```
$scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];
```

line of the code which is inside ajax call's done part is not setting date but the outer code is working as expected.

But i need the date values which is returned from server should be set.

Comment: why are you using ajax and not $http service?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$timeout(function () {
    $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];
}, 0);
```

Comment: I have tried using set time out but it still not working.